# Add a prefix to beginning of each line depending on its size

Tags: linux, scripting

I have a file with postal codes and city names like this :

```
1234  foo
4321  foobar
64324 foofoobar
92001 bar
```

with a \t between the numbers and the city name. I would like to add the prefix 0 to each line with 4 numbers, using sed or a shell script

```
01234 foo
04321 foobar
64324 foofoobar
92001 bar
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the postcodes are numeric, you can use the `printf` command in `awk` for the task, as per the following transcript (the `v` characters are there just to show where the tab stops are):

```
pax> printf "v\tv\tv\n" ; cat infile
v       v       v
1234    rio     xyz
4321    munich  abc
64324   perth   def
92001   paris   qqq

pax> awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} {arg1 = $1; $1 = ""; printf "%05d%s\n", arg1, $0}' infile
01234   rio     xyz
04321   munich  abc
64324   perth   def
92001   paris   qqq
```

The `awk` command first extracts *and removes* the first argument<sup>(a)</sup> from each line, then formats it along with the changed line.

You'll notice I've also set the output field separator to a tab character since that appears to be what you're using. That *may* not be necessary, it just depends on how closely you want the output data to match the input.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Technically it just sets it to an empty string, the argument itself still exists. That's why there's no tab needed between the `%05d` and `%s` in the format string, since the tab is still there.

Comment: I'm sorry I completely forgot my file had city names after the postal codes... I'm editing the post.

Comment: @Prefisk, no problems, I've updated the answer to incorporate your changed requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^\(....\)$/0\1/' filename
```

(But paxdiablo's answer is more legible, I think.)